# D3: X Axis values wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm new in d3.js and I've got a problem. I have made a component with React.js where I reuse in the same page. This component draws a scatter plot and the first time that I call this component show both axis correctly (the left one). But, the second time that I call it the x axis show wrong values but y axis show rigth values (the right one).

[image]

The value that I pass to the component for the graphic on the rigth are:

```
x: 5.56 y: 0.00
x: 5.56 y: 33.33
x: 44.44 y: 0.00
x: 0.00 y: 0.00
x: 22.22 y: 33.33
x: 0.00 y: 0.00
x: 0.00 y: 33.33
x: 22.22 y: 0.00
```

How you can see, the x min value is 0.00 and the x max value is 44.44, but we've got in the x axis like min -1.0 and the highest is 5.5

The code where I define the scales of the axis is:

```
setScales(data){ 
    let xRange = [this.state.margin.left, this.state.width - this.state.margin.right];
    let yRange = [this.state.margin.top, this.state.height - this.state.margin.top - this.state.margin.bottom]; // flip order because y-axis origin is upper LEFT  

    let xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([ d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value_x; }) - 1,
              d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value_x; }) + 1 ])
    .range(xRange);

    let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([ d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value_y; }) + 1,
              d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value_y; }) - 1 ])
    .range(yRange);       

    return {"xScale" : xScale, "yScale" : yScale, "xRange" : xRange, "yRange" : yRange};
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong? What happend?

Answer (score 0):

¡¡¡I have found the solution!!!!

I don't know why, but the problem is by the type of data. I have parsed the values to float an right now it works.

```
let xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([ d3.min(data, d => parseFloat(d.value_x)) + 1, d3.max(data, d => parseFloat(d.value_x)) - 1])
.range(xRange);
```

I don't know why it happens that because I've got the values from the same function that I've got he values for the left graphic.

Now, both graphics are correct.

[image]